# For loop in shell script - colons and hash marks?

Tags: shell, loops, sh

I am trying to make heads or tails of a shell script. Could someone please explain this line?

$FILEDIR is a directory containing files. F is a marker in an array of files that is returned from this command:
files=$( find $FILEDIR -type f  | grep -v .rpmsave\$ | grep -v .swp\$ )

The confusing line is within a for loop.

```
for f in $files; do
target=${f:${#FILEDIR}}
<<do some more stuff>>
done
```

I've never seen the colon, and the hash before in a shell script for loop. I haven't been able to find any documentation on them... could someone try and enlighten me? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `${f:${#FILEDIR}}` in bash gives the same result as the more portable expression `${f#$FILEDIR}`.  Both expressions remove the `$FILEDIR` prefix from `$f`.  The second expression is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no arrays involved here. POSIX sh doesn't have arrays (assuming you're not using another shell based upon the tags).

The colon indicates a Bash/Ksh [substring expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073). These are also not POSIX. The `#` prefix expands to the number of characters in the parameter. I imagine they intended to chop off the directory part and assign it to `target`.

To explain the rest of that: first [find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) is run and hilariously piped into two greps which do what could have been done with find alone (except breaking on possible filenames containing newlines), and the output saved into `files`. This is also something that can't really be done correctly if restricted only to POSIX tools, but there are better ways.

Next, `files` is expanded [unquoted](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and mutalated by the shell in more [ridiculous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) [ways](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for the `for` loop to iterate over the meaningless results. If the rest of the script is this bad, probably throw it out and start over. There's no way that will do what's expected.

Comment: Great, thank you for the links. I found the file in an rpm I'm dissecting and am trying to make sense of that one line since it will make a difference in how a single-sign-on package gets installed. Our security team wants us to deploy it but can't provide a list of changes it makes, so we can't tell what it will break. Much appreciated - I think I'll just run diff and make patch files :)

Answer (score 1):

The colon can be as a substring. So:

```
A=abcdefg
echo ${A:4}
```

will print the output:

```
efg
```

I'm not sure why they would use a file directory as the 2nd parameter though...

If you are having problems understanding the for loop section, try http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/loop-tutorial.php